# Should interface targets export its "optional" targets?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies

I have a custom general purpose `INTERFACE` target (*e.g.* **utils**) that, among other utilities, wraps around other 3rd party dependencies (e.g. [TinyXML2](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2)), and is being imported and linked to into another project of mine (*e.g.* **lib**).

From a *conceptual* standpoint, should  **lib** declare TinyXML2 and other 3rd party libraries as dependencies as needed, or just **utils** as a *catch-all* dependency (which is properly configured *i.e.* exports  all its dependencies to consuming projects)?
I understand that `find_package`ing, `install`ing and `export`ing "inherited" dependencies is, for practical purposes, entirely redundant in this case, but **utils** provides other tools beyond wrappers that optionally require linking to 3rd party libraries such as TinyXML2 - targets/projects linking to it may not require these dependencies at all, or alternatively, include/link resources from those 3rd parties directly.

I'm curious as to  what's the convention / proper practice in such cases?